# Transforming a double sum into a product of two sums.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, summation

Question is from Stein-Shakarchi Vol. I. I am asked to show that for two complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$, $e^{z_1}e^{z_2}=e^{z_1+z_2}$ using the definition of the complex exponential $e^z=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}$.

So I plugged in $(z_1+z_2)$ on the right and expanded using the binomial formula as follows:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(z_1+z_2)^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}z_1^{n-k}z_2^k}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{z_1^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}\frac{z_2^k}{k!}$$
Now I'm stuck in showing that what I've got can be reformulated as a product of two sums. I think I'll have to do something with the indices but can't see exactly what. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{z_1^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}\frac{z_2^k}{k!} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{I}\{k\le n\}\frac{z_1^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}\frac{z_2^k}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{I}\{k\le n\}\frac{z_1^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}\frac{z_2^k}{k!}
\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \frac{z_1^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}\frac{z_2^k}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z_1^{n}}{n!}\frac{z_2^k}{k!} 
\\
&= 
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z_1^{n}}{n!}\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z_2^k}{k!} = e^{z_1} \cdot e^{z_2}
\end{align*}

Comment: what's $\Bbb{I}$?

Comment: It is the indicator function symbol. So, $\mathbb{I}\{k \le n\}$ is defined to be $1$ if $k \le n$, and $0$ if $k>n$.

Answer (score 1):

$$e^{z_1}e^{z_2} = (1 + \frac {1}{1!}z_1 + \frac {1}{2!}z_1 ^2 + \frac {1}{3!}z_1 ^3 + ...)(1 + \frac {1}{1!}z_2 + \frac {1}{2!}z_2 ^2 + \frac {1}{3!}z_2 ^3 + ...)$$

$$= 1 + \frac {1}{1!}(z_1+z_2) + \frac {1}{2!}(z_1 ^2 + 2z_1z_2+z_2^2) + \frac{1}{3!}(z_1^3 + 3 z_1^2z_2 + 3z_1z_2^2 + z_2^3) + ...$$

$$= 1 + \frac {1}{1!}(z_1+z_2) + \frac {1}{2!}(z_1+z_2)^2 + \frac{1}{3!}(z_1 + z_2)^3 + ...$$
$$= e^{z_1+z_2}$$